# Azure Data Sync Between Two Azure Databases

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure, data-synchronization, sql-data-sync

I would like to ask if I use Azure data sync with my two azure databases is there any way that I can still download data tier and install it on my local machine. I am planning to create a sync between some of my tables inside my database A and copy its record to the database B at a specific time daily. is this possible on Azure Data Sync?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can sync up to 500 tables on a sync group (per user). So you just need to create a sync group and specify which tables you want to sync. You can have up to 5 sync groups per database.

You must have a hub database (it must be a SQL Azure Database) and you can have one or more member databases (let's say one on Azure SQL Database and another member SQL Server database on your local machine).